# How can I alternate between two kiosk-mode appplications?

Tags: xorg, upstart, steam, xbmc

I currently have a single-user system that autoloads into X and starts XBMC via a super-simple Upstart job that runs:

```
su -c "startx /etc/X11/Xsession /usr/bin/xbmc-standalone -- -bs" oli
```

Super-simple and it works, double-rock-solid... No desktop getting in the way. No window manager to slow down performance. And it bounces back when XBMC crashes (once a day). It's fantastic if all you want to do is use XBMC. But now I'd like to install Steam to play games. This raises some problems:

1. Steam and XBMC are going to fight over screen time (there's no window manager, remember) and audio devices. We need to close XBMC before starting Steam but **without killing X**. Note how XBMC is currently launched. How do I do that?
2. It'd also be really grand if I could trigger the XBMC→Steam switchover from my wireless XBox controller. It's hooked in with [`xboxdrv`](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/xboxdrv.html) which has an `exec` option:

   ```
   xboxdrv --ui-buttonmap XBOXBTN=exec:/home/oli/bin/switch.sh
   ```

   So assuming #1 can be  scripted, I can hook in.
3. The second half of #1. When Steam exists I need XBMC to come back up.
4. If whatever's currently running *crashes*, it needs to be the thing that loads back up.

So it seems my biggest problem is monitoring an application. If it exits gracefully (code 0, eg I've asked it to exit, or I've called a script that asked it to exit), it should load the other application and monitor it. If it crashed (not code-zero), it should run the same application and monitor it. Make sense? But *how*?

This all sort of feels like something Upstart would be great for except both are X applications running at user-level. I'm on 14.04 so if it has come far enough, that might be an option.

There may also be a way of doing this that's special to XBMC and/or Steam. I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: It is probably more complicated than this.. but grab pids at launch and just loop?

Comment: Might not even need the PID. As long as neither forks out, I could call one and keep it in the foreground and work out what happened when it dies. I'll give that some legs.

Answer (score 3):

This is just me thinking aloud. Here's a script that should alternate between two *blocking* commands

```
#!/bin/bash

XBMC="xbmc-standalone"
STEAM="steam steam://open/bigpicture"

current=$XBMC

openbox-session  # urgh required by Steam for keyboard IO

while true; do
    $current  # blocks until exit code

    [[ "$?" -ne "0" ]] && continue

    if [[ $current == $XBMC ]]; then
        current=$STEAM
    else
        current=$XBMC
    fi
done
```

If I can call this instead of `xbmc-standalone` at X start-up, that should allow the script to stay alive indefinitely (which would keep X alive).